# what is the order of the implementations in the array Symbian ECOM return?

Tags: plugins, symbian, ecom

REComSession::ListImplementationsL returns the impelementations in an array, accord to which .rsc files in \resource\plugins contain the certain interface ID. what is the mechanism to determine the order in that array?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An educated guess based on quickly browsing some of the [ECOM framework source](http://developer.symbian.org/xref/oss/xref/Symbian3/sf/os/ossrv/lowlevellibsandfws/pluginfw/Framework/frame/) would be that the implementations are sorted by UID3.

Comment: yes, should be it. should it be implementation id more precisely?